# MySQL syntax wrong

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
user(id, name);
advert(id,name,category_id,user_id);
category(id,category_name);
```

What i want to do is show for a certain user how many adverts he has in each category.
I have to use a sub-query.I've tried something like this but is not working at all.
What I've tried looks like this:

```
SELECT c.id,c.name count(advert) number_of_adverts
FROM category c
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING count(advert)=(SELECT count(a.id)
                     FROM advert a
                     INNER JOIN user ON a.user_id=u.id
                     WHERE u.id="1"
                     HAVING a.category_id=c.id);
```

I know this is wrong but i dont quite understand how should i do it to make it work.

Comment: Could you please style your SQL a little bit to increase the readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(a.id) AS number_of_adverts
FROM user u
JOIN advert a ON (u.id = a.user_id)
JOIN category c ON (c.id = a.category_id)
WHERE u.user_id = '999'
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

You can't use a sub-query as, there could be multiple categories and multiple adverts for each category.